# Pullback of Ring Spectra

Tags: commutative-algebra

let $\phi: R \to A$ a ring homomorphism and $f:Spec(A) \to Spec(R)$ the induced morphism on Specs. Let $p \in Spec(R)$. So $ R_p$ is local. This induces following commutative diagramm:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Spec(A_p) @>{a}  >> Spec(A) \\
@VVgV  @VVfV  \\
Spec(R_p) @>{b}>> Spec(R);
\end{CD}
$$

a, b are inclusions (see property of localisations) and g is induced by f canonically. My question is how to see that $Spec(A_p) \cong Spec(A) \times _{Spec(R)} Spec(R_p)$ (therefore a pullback)?

Comment: By definition $A_p=R_p\otimes_R A$ (note that $p$ is not necessarily a prime ideal in $A$). Tensor products are fibered coproducts and $\operatorname{Spec}$ sends tensor products to fibered products.

Comment: Why does Spec sends tensor producs to fibered products?

Comment: Do you know that there is a natural isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}_{Alg}(A,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))=\operatorname{Hom}_{Sch}(X,\operatorname{Spec}A)$ ? From this, it follows that $\operatorname{Spec}$ sends colimits to limits.